# Which is better, "Information and Communication Technology (ICT) discipline" or "the discipline of Information and Communication Technology (ICT)"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-order

I'm not sure which of the sentences to use:

> The proposed research topic requires **Information and Communication Technology (ICT) discipline** to successfully complete the research.

OR

> The proposed research topic requires **the discipline of Information and Communication Technology (ICT)** to successfully complete the research.

Comment: Both ***the** discipline of X* and *the X discipline* are fine. Note the definite article in the former, though.

Comment: *Disciple*, not so much

Answer (score 2):

Probably 'The proposed research topic requires the discipline of Information and Communication Technology (ICT)....'

You can find more assistance and resources to correctly write academically in this textbook 'Manipulate Your Marker' by Mitchell Grotte. It has many comprehensive lists of English techniques etc which may boost your marks and improve your skill.